# DBpedialookup client

Tags: java, tostring

I am trying to use the DBpedia look up service using DBpedia look up library by [Georgi Kobilarov](https://github.com/mark-watson/java_practical_semantic_web/blob/master/src/com/knowledgebooks/info_spiders/DBpediaLookupClient.java).

```
DBpediaLookupClient dbpedialookup = new DBpediaLookupClient("Car");
System.out.println("DBpedia Results = " + dbpedialookup.toString());
```

Somehow, I am not able to get the output. It still throws me only the memory location.

```
Output

method: http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryString=Car
org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod@4629104a
DBpedia Results = com.abcd.def.DBpediaLookupClient@3ac42916
```

Answer (score 0):

It was pretty simple. Strangely, I has missed out on that.

Either to get all the

```
System.out.println("DBpedia Results = " + dbpedialookup.variableBindings());
```

or

```
System.out.println(dbpedia.tempBinding);
```

to get an instance.